# Origin anchor pane is shown in 3D model when other window with controls is shown too

Tags: 3d, javafx

I have created a model in javafx using Spheres. I want to show second window with controls, to scale this 3D model.

But if this second window has some controls, the model is shown with anchor pane, where I put my shapes.
(I change scene color to black in code)

[image: With control]
[image: Without control]

Any idea how to remove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that pane is hidden in java while there are no controls at all. I removed pane and added shapes to group.